# What is the best way to convert a TFS project to a git repo

Tags: git, tfs

I know there have been a number of developments on support for git in the VS2012. We currently have a Team Foundation Server 2012 (Update 2) with all of our projects on it stored in the classic TFS format.

We are wanting to move from TFS to a pure git repo system (shared folder with git repos).

What is the best way to migrate our existing TFS projects into git repos so that they maintain their full commit log etc?

Is [TFS2Git](https://github.com/WilbertOnGithub/TFS2GIT) still the way to go?

Comment: This has been answered over here already -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548659/migrate-from-tfs-to-git-on-visualstudio-com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating from TFS to Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874873/migrating-from-tfs-to-git)

Answer (score 9):

There's an [article](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2013/06/16/Using-git-tf-to-migrate-code-between-TFS-servers-retaining-history.aspx) by Black Marble on using `git tf` and doing a clone with `--deep` to maintain history when transferring between TFS instances. The same should apply for migrating to Git.

Comment: +1'd but any chance you could move this answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874873/migrating-from-tfs-to-git and VTC this Q please?

Answer (score 0):

We migrated a year ago, and I tried tfs2git, it worked fine.  Though I decided to just start with the files and no history, as the history in TFS was not really useful for anything.

(It lingered in the TFS set to read-only if anyone would be interested, but that hardly ever happened at the start, and by now TFS is shut down for good...)

IME the real challenge is not that part of the migration but to design a sensible split and cooperation of repos, branching policy, teach people to rebase, stuff like that.