# Migrating a TFS repository to git

Tags: git, tfs

I'm going to happily switch from TFS to git. I can't afford losing the check-in history or my branches. What is the least painful way to convert my TFS repository into a git repository by turning each check-in to a git commit and keeping all the branches?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using the [`TFS2Git`](https://github.com/WilbertOnGithub/TFS2GIT) Powershell script. There's also a great [`Git-TF`](http://gittf.codeplex.com/) extension you might try:

```
git tf clone http://myserver:8080/tfs/mycollection $/TeamProjectA/Main
```

This will effectively keep all your source repository commit history when cloning.

Comment: +1 the right answer. Would you mind VTCing this Q and moving your answer to the cited earlier one please though?